# Returning Structure from C function, what will be C# equivalent?

Tags: c#, c, struct, interop, dllimport

can someone please help me with the following.

Following struct, when returned application blows up

```
typedef struct
{
    MY_INFO *array;
    size_t used;
   size_t size;
} MY_INFO_ARRAY;
```

Method Signature 
`MY_INFO_ARRAY WINAPI FInfoAll(char *p)`

I have tested it using C++ code works fine, now trying C# to call the the same method but it seems the dll blows up when returning

I have written the following C# implementation to received the structure, also DLL import function is completed

New Class to received the struct above.

```
public class MyInformationArray 
{
    public Int32 Count { get; internal set; }


    public Int32 Size { get; internal set; }

    public MY_INFO[] { get; internal set; }


}
```

calling as follows

```
MyInformationArray minfo = FInfoAll(".");
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is the behaviour as expected, but the compiled assembly is larger than desired?

Comment: I'd suppose that you need a value type (struct) in C# to get the layout of a C struct. I also suppose that a C# array won't correspond to a C++ pointer. And: Where does that pointer actually point?

Comment: You may want to look at [How to Marshal C++ structs in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx).

Comment: You've omitted lots important detail. There's code missing and you've not described how it fails. "Blows up" is no use. What you need to do is include complete code for both sides of the interop. However, it should be clear that the structs don't match. Even if they did, you'll need to do some manual work to marshall the array.

Comment: I will put together example code. structures do map, what sort of marshaling you are mean. please be aware that I am not a C developer so please be prescriptive, with example.

Comment: 1. A marshalled class need a sequential layout. 2. A marshalled class is already a 'pointer'. 3. DateTime cannot be marshalled from a char array. 4. size_t is unsigned and bitness dependent. 5. You cannot marshal properties, they need to be fields. And so on and on and on. Edit: You will have better luck using c++/cli here.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure translation is wrong. You also will need to marshal the array manually. And you'll need to deal with deallocation of the array. I guess the unmanaged codes needs to do that but it depends how it was allocated.

The struct should be

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MY_INFO_ARRAY
{
    public IntPtr array;
    public UIntPtr used;
    public UIntPtr size;
}
```

Once you've got one these you'll need to call `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to get each element of the array.

The `size` and `used` parameters are declared as `UIntPtr` since `size_t` is 32 or 64 bits dependent on the machine architecture.

It would be far easier to return the array via a parameter. And have the caller allocate the memory. Then the marshaler could do the work for you.

Comment: I have submitted the example C# code which is calling mydll written in C.

Comment: I reverted your edit. That's a different question. Please can. We deal with this question first.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why explicit layout? Does that not *require* `FieldOffset` on every field too?

Comment: David I have taken your suggestion and provided the working C# example also now I am using the parameter as well as advised therefore hopping it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @Warrior You changed the question completely which made this answer invalid. This is a Q&A site

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sequential is also redundant on a struct, but I still see many people use it, like redundant this, private, internal, etc.

Comment: @leppie I've never seen documentation that sequential is defaiult

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you look at the IL, you will see it is there. I think I recall seeing it defined in the CIL spec. Funny enough, you can use Auto on structs. Not sure what will happen then!

Comment: @leppie I know from experience that is so, but I've never seen it specified. So perhaps safe to be explicit about the layout. Although not if one idiotically writes the wrong value!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Perhaps a good question to ask, but the following from ECMA-335 (II.22.8) "If any type within an inheritance
chain has layout, then so shall all its base classes, up to the one that descends immediately from
System.ValueType (if it exists in the type’s hierarchy); otherwise, from System.Object." seems to indicate the semantics. The weird bit is that `ValueType` is `auto`. Still not a definitive answer.

Comment: @leppie you should ask the question! I'd be very interested.

Comment: @leppie see the "Remarks" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.100).aspx : "C#, Visual Basic, and C++ compilers apply the Sequential layout value to structures by default. "